# Properly setting Cake routes with parameters

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I'm making my first page which requires a parameter called `$hash`. My route is currently this:

```
Router::connect('/activate/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'activate'));
```

which works almost perfectly, but if I enter a URL like:

```
http://localhost/activate/something/somethingelse/long/url
```

it matches the route. I want it to only match one 32 character long parameter like this:

```
http://localhost/activate/ajsheeugnbloiuffheogysswhvnntpdd
```

and for everything else to lead to a 404. What's the correct method of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the regex matching for the route something like

```
Router::connect(
    '/activate/:id',
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'activate'),
    array('id' => '[a-zA-Z]{32}')
);
```

you can adjust the regex, currently it's just letters.

Here's the reference: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements

Comment: You'll probably want to add this to the last array in order to have 'id' being passed as the first argument to the activate action; 'pass' => array('id')